# Page serving in development but not in Heroku production

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a password reset function in my nodejs/express application that sends a user an email via Sendgrid to enter a new password if they have forgotten.

The email contains a button that's clicked to open a page with a reset token in the url params. This page renders correctly from email button click when I run the application locally, but on the production server it returns an error, apparently unable to find the page.

The logs look like this:

```
ERROR {
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634102+00:00 app[web.1]:   view: View {
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634104+00:00 app[web.1]:     defaultEngine: 'pug',
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634104+00:00 app[web.1]:     ext: '.pug',
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634104+00:00 app[web.1]:     name: 'resetpassword',
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634105+00:00 app[web.1]:     root: '/app/views',
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634105+00:00 app[web.1]:     engine: [Function],
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634106+00:00 app[web.1]:     path: undefined
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634106+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634106+00:00 app[web.1]:   statusCode: 500,
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634107+00:00 app[web.1]:   status: 'error',
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634108+00:00 app[web.1]:   message: 'Failed to lookup view "resetpassword" in views directory "/app/views"'
2021-01-13T08:23:33.634108+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I'm not sure how it can find the html template in development but not in production when the code is the same.

The route looks like this:

```
router.get('/resetPassword/:token', controller.getResetPasswordForm)

exports.getResetPasswordForm = (req, res) => {
res.status(200).render('resetpassword', {
    title: 'Reset password',
    resetToken: req.params.token
})
}
```

The only thing I can think of it's that it's something to do with Heroku, and where the template is relative to the root directory, so perhaps the "root: '/app/views". I have added a new domain name to the app recently (so it's not just '....herokuapp.com').

Is this a problem with the relative path? Is it a problem with Heroku if it works on my dev server?

Comment: can you add you routes details and also the path were the values are being served ?

Comment: the path should be just '.../views/resetPassword.pug'.

Comment: I cant help until I see the way you are serving it in main app. If you can add that code, I can get some idea where things could be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following you - my route for this page is just the root of the application with a GET request to the url '/resetPassword/:token' which should render the file that's at '/theapplication/views/resetPassword.pug'. Which works locally. I'll try and edit to post the code, but it'll be a bit messy......

Comment: It feels like you current working directory might not getting mapped correctly. Can you try adding `process.cwd() + '/views'` where you are setting you view engine in the main js file ?

Comment: That's what it feels like to me, and I'm wondering if it's because of a problem with the root directory. At the moment I set the view engine like this - "app.set('view engine', 'pug').  
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))", so I would've thought it should just take the correct/current directory name and join it on.

Comment: try the above solution. It should get fixed by that

Comment: When I tried it with this line of code "app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, process.cwd() + '/views'))" it just gives me a server error.

Comment: you cannot use both, just use process.cwd()

Comment: Still didn't work I'm afraid, the problem is the same. I think the problem might be that Heroku is confused about what is the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that Heroku must care about capitalisation, because the pug template is called 'resetPassword', and I had nodejs render a template called 'resetpassword'. This was apparently acceptable locally, but not for Heroku's server.